# Issue with Web Scraping in Python Using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently working on a web scraping project in Python, using the requests library in conjunction with BeautifulSoup. However, I am encountering an issue while attempting to extract specific content from a webpage. Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.metacritic.com/browse/movie/all/all/all-time/new/?releaseYearMin=1910&releaseYearMax=2023&page=1"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
target_div = soup.find("div", {"class": "c-productListings"})

print(target_div)
```

The target_div I am trying to extract is from the URL mentioned in the code. However, when I run the script, the target_div seems to be empty, and the printed output is None. I have verified that the URL is accessible and that the HTML structure seems to contain the specified div class.

I have tried using different parsers for BeautifulSoup and also ensured that the request to the URL is successful. Despite these efforts, I am unable to fetch the desired content.

Could someone please guide me on what might be causing this issue? Is there a problem with my approach to scraping the webpage, or is there a better way to locate the required content? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `print(soup)` then it tells you the reason

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: You don't have headers with a proper `User-Agent`. I've supplied a few old ones that worked for my test but, [this site](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/) has lists of current ones.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, random


AGENTS = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
          'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')

#create headers
HEADERS               = requests.utils.default_headers()
HEADERS['User-Agent'] = random.choice(AGENTS)

url = "https://www.metacritic.com/browse/movie/all/all/all-time/new/?releaseYearMin=1910&releaseYearMax=2023&page=1"

page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
target_div = soup.find("div", {"class": "c-productListings"})
```